# Wordpress -- Logged in state not persisted between http/https

Tags: php, wordpress, http, cookies, https

I'm managing a Wordpress site on which we are supporting HTTPS for some checkout functionality. We need all pages on the site to work on HTTPS and for performance reasons, we want pretty much everything to work on HTTP.

I'm running into a problem where a user has to log in to both HTTP & HTTPS. Looking at the cookies, when a user is logged in, there are a pair of cookies for each.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score -1):

Since v2.6, Wordpress uses three cookies to manage site authentication, so that a site can support users over both http and https. There's a good writeup by [Ryan Boren](http://ryan.boren.me/2008/07/14/ssl-and-cookies-in-wordpress-26/).

The effect this has is that, when a user logs in to admin over https, the site will know (s)he is logged in (for edit/logout links on the front end) over both http and https, but the user will need to re-login to get into the admin over http.

The solution is to force the admin area to always use ssl, by adding `define(‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’, true);` to your `wp-config.php` file.